# JFrog Artifactory Exporter,How to use it on windows?

Tags: prometheus, artifactory

I download it from git, because I want to use it for monitor Artifactory[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J2mS.png)

and I set env varfiables in my windows:ARTI_USERNAME ,ARTI_PASSOWORD,ARTI_ACCESS_TOKEN

But I can not run it as expected
Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppy0p.png)

I want run it success

Please tell me what shoud I do for it

Thanks so much！

Comment: How you added variables? Have you restarted your command line after that? Can you run command `set` before and after restart of cmd and see your variables there?

Comment: Yes, I set env by cmd, and if I cloesd cmd window ,reOpen cmd  write echo %variable name% also can get varfiable value . I think this is expected.

Comment: about run artifactory_expoter, I run it by double click , do I need add some flags for it?

Comment: @markalex，Hi markalex ，Do you know how I can run this artifactory_exporter.exe correctly? This is git link,https://github.com/peimanja/artifactory_exporter,Thank you so much!

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with this exporter. You can try starting exe from the cmd, where you verified env variables, as I'm not 100% sure if variables will be seen by explorer (which will be a parent to app started with double click)

Comment: Hi markalex , I can run it  succeed，Issue reason
1.ARTI_USERNAME and ARTI_PASSWORD cannot exist in environment variables at the same time as ARTI_ACCESS_TOKEN
Thank you!

Comment: are you sure? Because I quickly glanced over code in the repo, and it looked like it should work with all three simply using username/pass.

Comment: Yes，I'm sure, I tried it many times with the same result, if you are interested you can download one and try to launch it，Thanks!